# year minus 1 in oracle( go to previous year)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i  have a table groups which has a filed year  with datatype as varchar2 and the data in it look like(

```
year_cd
FY15
FY16
FY17 and so on
```

)
 what i need is , I am trying to do a minus 1 year for a particular year like if i take FY17 i need to do a minus 1 year.
some thing like this
select to_char(add_months(year_cd,-12)) from aaa.groups
 but it says non-numeric character was found where numeric was expected . please help

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `add_months` directly on FYXX.

```
with t(year_cd) as (
  select 'FY15' from dual union all
  select 'FY16' from dual union all
  select 'FY17' from dual
  )
select 
  year_cd,
  to_char(add_months(to_date(year_cd, '"FY"YY'), -12), '"FY"YY') last_year_cd
from t;
```

Produces:

```
YEAR_CD LAST_YEAR_CD
--------------------
FY15    FY14
FY16    FY15
FY17    FY16
```

Comment: to_date(year_cd,'"FY"YY')

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - Awesome! Didn't realize I could use literal :) Thanks